# You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled when migrating a routine in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to add [Bagisto](https://bagisto.com) to my application stack on the CNAME `shop` so I added a new SQL database to host this in Docker-Compose.

When I `docker exec -it -u root my_php_container bash` and run `php artisan migrate` I get this when it attempts to create a routine.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1419 You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you **might** want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_functio
> n_creators variable)

My docker-compose container looks like this:

```
mysql:
  image: 'mysql:latest'
  restart: 'unless-stopped'
  expose:
  - '3306'
  environment:
  - 'MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}'
  - 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
  - 'MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}'
  - 'MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
  volumes:
  - 'laravel-db:/var/lib/mysql/'
  networks:
  - 'laravel'
```

I [took a look on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56390000/5897602) but cannot find the env for the [mysql docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) that regards to this. I tried to add an Entrypoint that just ran an export for `log_bin_trust_function_creators=1` but this hasn't worked. Any help appreciated.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this one `SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;` before running the `docker exec -it -u root my_php_container bash` or `php artisan migrate`.

For this you have to login as mysql user and in mysql terminal you have to execute `SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;`.

Comment: I had to `docker exec -it -u root mysql bash` then run `mysql -u root -p table_name` and login as root then execute the `SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;` thankyou!